# Why is my unit test failing when saving a json string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, junit

Why is my unit test failing when saving a json string?

Here is my unit test.

```
@Test
void save() {
    PoiDto saveDto = createPoi();

    Poi entity = poiRepository.findById(saveDto.id()).orElseThrow();

    assertEquals(saveDto.id(), entity.getId());
    assertEquals(saveDto.code(), entity.getCode());
    assertEquals(saveDto.position(), entity.getPosition());
    assertEquals("\"" + saveDto.position() + "\"", entity.getPosition());
}
```

3<sup>rd</sup> assert does not pass but the 4<sup>th</sup> assert passes.

The error is:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
Expected :{x: 75, y: 40, z: 13}
Actual :"{x: 75, y: 40, z: 13}"
```

I wonder why `""` is appended when searching json with entity.

I'm also wondering how I should modify this test code.

Comment: Can you please edit and add the structure of PoiDto and Poi Classes as well ?

Comment: Looks like `saveDto.position()` returns an object instead of a String.

Comment: Use `assertEquals(saveDto.position().toString(), entity.getPosition());`!?

Comment: But this relies (I would not) on "order" of x,y,z (in the resulting string...json is different !)

Comment: to expand on xerx593's comment, instead of toString I would instead change the string to a dict but using json.loads. For example `assertEquals(saveDto.position(), json.loads(entity.getPosition()));`

Answer (score 0):

I sovled as like below

`Assertions.assertThat(a).isEqualTo(b)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).